# c# .net core certificate chain on linux fails, windows works

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, certificate, x509certificate2

I create a self sign certificate in debug with .net core and store it into the certificate store (my/root). When the app runs under windows the certificate cain is okay but under linux (ubuntu) the certificate chain check fails.

Certificate creation code is:

```
public static X509Certificate2 BuildSelfSignedServerCertificate()
{
  using RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048);

  var request = new CertificateRequest("CN=My_Certificate", 
      rsa, 
      HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, 
      RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

 request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
      new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DataEncipherment |
      X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyEncipherment | X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, false));

  request.CertificateExtensions
     .Add(new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(request.PublicKey, false));

  request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
     new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
         new OidCollection { 
           new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"), 
           new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2") }, false));

  var certificate = request.CreateSelfSigned(new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1)), 
       new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(3650)));
  LogFileLevelInformation("Created new self sign certificate.");
  return certificate;
}
```

Then I add the certificate at my and root stores:

```
public static void CreateCert()
{
  var certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
  certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
  bool result = certificateStore.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>()
    .Any(cert => cert.Subject.Contains("My_Certificate"));
  if (result)
    return;


  var cert = BuildSelfSignedServerCertificate();
  certificateStore.Add(cert);
  certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
  certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
  certificateStore.Add(cert);
  LogFileLevelInformation("New certificate added to store.");
}
```

then later I verify the chain:

```
private X509Certificate2 VerifyCertificateChain(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
  var chain = new X509Chain();
  chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
  chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
  chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

  var chainBuilt = chain.Build(certificate);

  if (chainBuilt)
  {
    LogDebugLevelInformation("The certificate chain is validated.")
    return certificate;
  }
  return null;
 }
```

the certificate check under windows with

```
 var chainBuilt = chain.Build(certificate);
```

returns with result true, but when the same code runs under linux it returns false.

the certificate is available on linux under:

/root/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/root

and

/root/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my

chain.StatusCode = "unable to get local issuer certificate"

Any idea why it is failing under linux?

Comment: Maybe it is the encoding.  See : https://www.tecmint.com/convert-files-to-utf-8-encoding-in-linux/

Comment: certificate creation is on linux itself

Comment: Does application have privilege to read certificate?

Comment: There are some caches in process to speed up chain building, they normally get correctly invalidated when you modify the stores, but sometimes they don’t get the memo (particularly if last write times are disabled, or you’ve done a lot of work in a short time). It should work if you add it to the store, and then check it in a new process... if so, there’s probably also an amount of time you can sleep to make it work in the same process.

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue and haven't been found a solution. Have you found a resolution?